# During the weekend or during the weekends?

Tags: grammar

During the weekend or during the weekends?

> I am too lazy to do anything but sleep during the weekend.

> I am too lazy to do anything but sleep during the weekends.

I am speaking about all weekends, so it should be plural, but I thought maybe it can also be singular.

Comment: We usually favour the singular in such contexts (even when it's a generic reference to "every weekend"), and [*the most common preposition is **over***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rest+over+the+weekend%2Crest+during+the+weekend%2Crest+on+the+weekend&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). As a Brit, I don't like ***during*** or ***on*** here, but they both seem to be relatively common alternatives for Americans. I should also say that I don't have much of a problem with ***on***, providing it's plural *I sleep on **weekends*** with no preceding article.

Comment: Here in Canada, "...on the weekend" or "...on weekends" (without "the") are both natural. "...during weekends" (without "the") is grammatically correct, but not natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both of them were right. Because if you count the weekend to Saturday and Sunday, you can use 'Weekends'. But if you count weekend to one weekend, you can use 'Weekend'.

Answer (score -1):

The more accurate usage would be **weekends**: you refer to as all of the weekend(s), however due to normality it is widely accepted to be correct either way. This is because due to evolution, "weekend" in the context of this sentence is seen as a collective term of every weekend.

However "weekends" tend to be received as every weekend while "weekend" when received short-sightedly may indicate to mean a weekend.

The usage of during indicates a present tense and it may confuse readers because you are referring to an event in the past.

In a conversation tone it would normally be easily dismissed.